# How to add contour labels for contour lines?

Tags: plotting, labeling

How can I add contour labels to contour lines? The usual `ContourLabels->Automatic` doesn't seem to be working when the input is given in the third form of [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html).

```
labelFontSize = 24;
ticksFontSize = 16;
lineThickness = 2;

contourPlotToF = ContourPlot[
tArrival - tDeparture == Table[Δt, {Δt, 0, 70, 7}],
{tDeparture, 30, 60}, {tArrival, 30, 60},
ImageSize -> Full,
FrameLabel -> {Row[{"Departure time/", Quantity[None, "Days"]}], 
Row[{"Arrival time/", Quantity[None, "Days"]}]},
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> ticksFontSize],
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> labelFontSize},
ContourLabels -> Automatic,
ContourStyle -> {Directive[
  ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[4]],
  AbsoluteThickness[lineThickness]]},
GridLines -> Automatic
]
```

Edit:

As per @Michael E2 suggestion, I've altered

```
tArrival - tDeparture == Table[Δt, {Δt, 0, 70, 7}],
```

to

```
Evaluate[Thread[tArrival-tDeparture==Table[Δt,{Δt, 0, 70, 7}]]],
```

which is producing the following result:
[image: Contour plot]

The label is appearing only when I hover the line, and just giving the list of contours. What I use for "traditional" contour plots is

```
ContourLabels -> (Text[Style[#3, ticksFontSize], {#1, #2}] &),
```

for the labels to appear next to the lines. However, this doesn't seem to work here.

PS: By "traditional" contour plots, I mean of the first form of [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html), with the colour coded in-between contours.

Comment: The third form, strictly speaking, is given by `ContourPlot[Evaluate[Thread[tArrival - tDeparture == Table[\[CapitalDelta]t, {\[CapitalDelta]t, 0, 70, 7}]]],...]`. The labels and styling of plots come from the given form, before it is processed for plotting.

Comment: @BobHanlon That way I get a "traditional" contour plot, whereas I want only the lines...

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for the correction. Still, the labels are only appearing when I hover, and are the same for every contour (I edited the question to include what I'm getting). Is it possible to add each contour value next to the line? The code I use for "traditional" contour plots does not work here (also included in the edit).

Comment: @BobHanlon This seems to do the trick, thank you! Would you mind turning the comment into an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: When the input is in the form of an equation, either the second or third paradigm in the docs, `ContourPlot` treats the equation as the label. Since the numerical value on each side of an equation may vary along the solution curve, the value is not treated as significant. I think @Bob's approach can probably be adapted to your needs more easily than using the third form.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230494/is-contourlabels-broken-when-input-to-contourplot-is-an-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, use the first form

```
Clear["Global`*"]

labelFontSize = 24;
ticksFontSize = 16;
lineThickness = 2;

ContourPlot[tArrival - tDeparture,
 {tDeparture, 30, 60}, {tArrival, 30, 60},
 Contours -> Range[0, 70, 7],
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 FrameLabel -> {
   Row[{"Departure time/", Quantity[None, "Days"]}],
   Row[{"Arrival time/", Quantity[None, "Days"]}]}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> ticksFontSize], 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> labelFontSize},
 ContourLabels ->
  (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &), 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[4]], AbsoluteThickness[lineThickness]],
 ContourShading -> None,
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]