# Is ContourLabels broken when input to ContourPlot is an equation?

Tags: plotting, labeling

Since this behavior is connected to [How to add contour labels for contour lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230440/how-to-add-contour-labels-for-contour-lines),
I thought it worth pointing out this issue here on the site.  It concerns the option `ContourLabels` to `ContourPlot`, when the form is

```
ContourLabels -> f
```

where `f` is a function of the form `f[x, y, z]` that constructs a label for the point `{x, y}` and label `z`.

In the first paradigm `ContourPlot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin], ymax]}]` the labels are constructed as one would expect:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  Contours -> {0.5}, ContourShading -> None, 
  ContourLabels -> (Text[0.5, {#1, #2}] & @@ Sow[{##}] &)] // Reap
```

[image]

In the second paradigm `ContourPlot[f == g, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin], ymax]}]` the labels are constructed but discarded:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y] == 0.5, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ContourLabels -> (Text[0.5, {#1, #2}] & @@ Sow[{##}] &)] // Reap
```

[image]

If one compares the graphics, in the first case, there are two `Inset[]` expressions, one for each label.  In the second, there are no `Inset[]` expressions.

The fact that the third `z` argument to the label constructor is different in the two cases is expected and seems irrelevant to the issue.

Another probably irrelevant observation is that the following does construct a `Tooltip` for each curve, although the labels are still discarded:

```
ContourLabels -> {Text[0.5, {#1, #2}] &, Tooltip[#1, #2] &}
```

Is there a way to get `ContourLabels` to work when the input is an equation or list of equations?  Is it a bug?